# phonegap remote build and cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview not working together

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, cordova-plugins

That is my config.xml:

```
...
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" source="npm" />
<!--<gap:plugin name='cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview' source="npm" />-->
<gap:plugin name='org.crosswalk.engine' source="pgb" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" />
...
```

and this working ok, but when i add plugin by npm (as a second line)
phonegap remote build fail - without any specific error message. Just:

```
"[error] error occured while building the android app"
```

So what i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i find out whats happens:

http://phonegap.com/blog/2015/06/16/phonegap-updated-on-build/

> Note that the source in the plugin xml above is ‘pgb’, not ‘npm’. You’ll find that building with the npm version of cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview will fail on PhoneGap Build. Currently PGB doesn’t support gradle builds, so we had to fork the Crosswalk plugin and convert it to an ant project. Believe us, we don’t want to maintain a separate fork, so rest assured we are investigating gradle support on PGB and other solutions.